# Invalid signature - provided signature does not match - status 401

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, api, curl

I'm getting error Invalid signature - provided signature does not match-status 401. When I getting data in Laravel site from wordpress site. Trying to get single product details from wordpress site. But, all the sime I getting Invalid signature - provided signature does not match. How to solve this problem any idea? Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

```
$nonce = md5(mt_rand());
$base_string = 'GET&my_url?oauth_consumer_key=my_consumer_key&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp='.time().'&oauth_nonce='.$nonce.'&oauth_version=1.0';
     
$signature = hash_hmac( 'sha1', $base_string, 'my_consumer_secret', true);
   
$sig = base64_encode($signature);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'my_url?oauth_consumer_key=my_consumer_key&oauth_signature_method=HMAC- 
    SHA1&oauth_timestamp='.time().'&oauth_nonce='.$nonce.'&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature='.$sig,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
 ));
        
$response = curl_exec($curl);
        
curl_close($curl);
        
return $response;
```

Comment: Just to check, did you change the `my_consumer_key` parameter?

Comment: Yes, I changed my_consumer_key. But, same problem.